# Random HTML elements are unaffected by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a rather weird issue with this page. The page itself is pretty ugly, which probably doesn't help the situation much.

In the code, you will see that when an item is selected from a drop down, a javascript function is called up which is supposed to make some hidden items visible based on which item was selected. However, when there are upwards of 20 records on the page, some elements are randomly skipped and remain hidden. Its quite bizarre as there is seemingly no pattern to which elements are skipped.

Here is the javascript function (the second 'if' is where i think the issue is):

```
function fncEnable(x)
   {
        theform=document.form1      

            //first, we reset everything to be hidden and unchecked
        document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("when2"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("second"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("when3"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("third"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("when4"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("fourth"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("sun"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("mon"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("tues"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("wed"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("thurs"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("fri"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("sat"+x).checked = false;

        if(document.getElementById("howoften"+x).value == 1)
        {
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";//randomly, this line is skipped.

        }
        if(document.getElementById("howoften"+x).value == 2)
        {
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "visible";//this line is never skipped;
            document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";//randomly, this line is skipped.
            document.getElementById("when2"+x).style.visibility = "visible";//this line is never skipped.
            document.getElementById("second"+x).style.visibility = "visible";//this line, is never skipped.

        }

        if(document.getElementById("howoften"+x).value == 3)
        {
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("when2"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("second"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("when3"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("third"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        }

        if(document.getElementById("howoften"+x).value == 4)
        {
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).checked = true;
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("when2"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("second"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("when3"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("third"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("when4"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("fourth"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        }




        if(document.getElementById("howoften"+x).value == 5)
        {
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        }


        if(document.getElementById("howoften"+x).value == 6)
        {
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        }

        if(document.getElementById("howoften"+x).value == 7)
        {
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        }

        if(document.getElementById("howoften"+x).value == 8)
        {
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).checked = false;

        }

        if(document.getElementById("howoften"+x).value == 9)
        {
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).checked = false;

        }
        if(document.getElementById("howoften"+x).value == 10)
        {
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).checked = false;
            document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";

        }

        if(document.getElementById("howoften"+x).value == 11)
        {

            document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";

        }

        if(document.getElementById("howoften"+x).value == 12)
        {
            document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";

        }
   }
```

Any ideas as to why those lines are skipped?

**UPDATE:**
I went through and redid the function a little bit so it would be smaller, and I still get the same behavior.

```
function fncEnable(x)
    {
    var howoften = document.getElementById("howoften"+x).value;
    if(howoften == 1 || howoften == 2 || howoften == 3 || howoften == 4)
    {
        document.getElementById("sun"+x).checked = true;
        document.getElementById("mon"+x).checked = true;
        document.getElementById("tues"+x).checked = true;
        document.getElementById("wed"+x).checked = true;
        document.getElementById("thurs"+x).checked = true;
        document.getElementById("fri"+x).checked = true;
        document.getElementById("sat"+x).checked = true;
        document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = false;
    }
    else if (howoften == 7)
    {
        document.getElementById("sun"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("mon"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("tues"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("wed"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("thurs"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("fri"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("sat"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("sun"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("mon"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("tues"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("wed"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("thurs"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("fri"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("sat"+x).checked = false;
        document.getElementById("sun"+x).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("mon"+x).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("tues"+x).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("wed"+x).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("thurs"+x).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("fri"+x).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("sat"+x).disabled = true;
    }

    if(howoften == 4)
    {
        document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";

        document.getElementById("when2"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("second"+x).style.visibility = "visible";

        document.getElementById("when3"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("third"+x).style.visibility = "visible";

        document.getElementById("when4"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("fourth"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    else if (howoften == 3)
    {
        document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";

        document.getElementById("when2"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("second"+x).style.visibility = "visible";

        document.getElementById("when3"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("third"+x).style.visibility = "visible";

        document.getElementById("when4"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("fourth"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else if (howoften == 2)
    {
        document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";

        document.getElementById("when2"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("second"+x).style.visibility = "visible";

        document.getElementById("when3"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("third"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";

        document.getElementById("when4"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("fourth"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else if (howoften == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";

        document.getElementById("when2"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("second"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";

        document.getElementById("when3"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("third"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";

        document.getElementById("when4"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("fourth"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("when"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";

        document.getElementById("when2"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("second"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";

        document.getElementById("when3"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("third"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";

        document.getElementById("when4"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("fourth"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
```

Its probably not the best way, but it only took a few minutes.

As for the HTML, it looks well formed to me, but I could be missing something. Here are the relevant elements:

```
<table border="0" align="left" style="padding-bottom:10px">
    <tr valign="baseline">
        <td align="left" width="25%">Day(s) of the Week: </td>
        <td>Sun</td>
        <td>Mon</td>
        <td>Tues</td>
        <td>Wed</td>
        <td>Thurs</td>
        <td>Fri</td>
        <td>Sat</td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="baseline">

        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="sun<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>"   name="sun<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>"   value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="mon<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>"   name="mon<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>"   value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="tues<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>"  name="tues<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>"  value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="wed<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>"   name="wed<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>"   value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="thurs<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>" name="thurs<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="fri<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>"   name="fri<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>"   value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="sat<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>"   name="sat<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>"   value="" /></td>

    </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" align="left" style="padding-bottom:10px">
    <tr valign="baseline">
        <td width="25%"><label style="visibility:hidden" id="first<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>">Dose Time:</label></td>
        <td width="25%"><label style="visibility:hidden" id="second<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>">Second Dose:</label></td>
        <td width="25%"><label style="visibility:hidden" id="third<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>">Third Dose:</label></td>
        <td width="25%"><label style="visibility:hidden" id="fourth<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>">Fourth Dose:</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="when<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>"  style="visibility:hidden" size="1" id="when<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>">
                <option value="">Select A Time</option>
                <cfloop query="thetimes">
                    <option value="<cfoutput>#TimeFormat(thetimes.hourlytimes,'h:mm tt')#</cfoutput>"><cfoutput>#TimeFormat(thetimes.hourlytimes,'h:mm tt')#</cfoutput></option>
                </cfloop>
            </select>
            &nbsp;
        </td>


        <td>
            <select name="when2<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>" style="visibility:hidden"  size="1"  id="when2<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>">
                <option value="">Select A Time</option>
                <cfloop query="thetimes">
                    <option value="<cfoutput>#TimeFormat(thetimes.hourlytimes,'h:mm tt')#</cfoutput>"><cfoutput>#TimeFormat(thetimes.hourlytimes,'h:mm tt')#</cfoutput></option>
                </cfloop>
            </select>
            &nbsp;
        </td>


        <td>
            <select name="when3<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>" style="visibility:hidden"  size="1"  id="when3<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>">
                <option value="">Select A Time</option>
                <cfloop query="thetimes">
                    <option value="<cfoutput>#TimeFormat(thetimes.hourlytimes,'h:mm tt')#</cfoutput>"><cfoutput>#TimeFormat(thetimes.hourlytimes,'h:mm tt')#</cfoutput></option>
                </cfloop>
            </select>
            &nbsp;
        </td>

        <td>
            <select name="when4<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>" style="visibility:hidden"  size="1"  id="when4<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>">
                <option value="">Select A Time</option>
                <cfloop query="thetimes">
                    <option value="<cfoutput>#TimeFormat(thetimes.hourlytimes,'h:mm tt')#</cfoutput>"><cfoutput>#TimeFormat(thetimes.hourlytimes,'h:mm tt')#</cfoutput></option>
                </cfloop>
                </select>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I know this is horrifying, but that's why I don't want to have to redo it. I've got my own stuff to do, and I don't want to spend a ton of time redoing others' work if I can avoid it.

**UPDATE 2:**
I just discovered something. I don't know if it will help, but I'll mention it anyway.

I found that if i throw the offending element's visibility in an alert, it says "visible", but the element is definitely not visible on the page.

I also found that the behavior is the same in Firefox.

<s>Its starting to look like its always the 21st element, so "when21".</s>
scratch that. Its only on elements that end in 0 that work. so like `when40` and `when30` show up, but not `when31` or `when25`.

Comment: Are you sure your HTML is valid?

Comment: Need bleach for my eyes asap....seriosuly though, have you considered shortening this any? E.g. object maps, etc.

Comment: Which browsers have you tested this in?

Comment: This code makes me want to cry. I'm so sorry that you have to read this. I'm working on an answer, I just wanted to send my sympathies to you.

Comment: crazy idea: change each subsequent 'if' to an 'else if' to make sure more than one condition isn't getting triggered somehow.

Comment: I know. its bad. I was basically taking a shot in the dark here, hoping to get out of rewriting it. I guess I'll just do that.

Comment: @Jimmy So much redundancy... Please open a new question asking how to get rid of the redundancy in the above code!

Comment: I do realize this, but I have no intentions of fixing it in this instance. I didn't originally write this page, it was my coworker. And when she couldn't figure out her own code, it was up to me to decipher it. I'm just glad to have it working in some way so I can move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what I came up with.

All I did was change the name of the `when + x` drop down to `when1 + x`.

So:

```
 if(howoften != 8 && howoften != 9)
    {
        document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("when1"+x).style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("when1"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("first"+x).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

... etc...
```

and

```
<select name="when1<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>"  style="visibility:hidden" size="1" id="when1<cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>">
    <option value="">Select A Time</option>
    <cfloop query="thetimes">
         <option value="<cfoutput>#TimeFormat(thetimes.hourlytimes,'h:mm tt')#</cfoutput>"><cfoutput>#TimeFormat(thetimes.hourlytimes,'h:mm tt')#</cfoutput></option>
    </cfloop>
</select>
```

For some reason I don't understand, everything works just fine now. I had even tried just changing `when` to something like `j_thing` and it still didn't work. It was only when it had the '1' in there did it work.

If someone can explain why this works, I'd be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at the case, and possibly duplicated ID in your HTML document.

beside, you can have some issues due to the use of `visibility` in some case. Try to do some test with `display: none` instead `visibility: hidden`.

For display again the element, you can use `display: block`, `display: inline`, or [the other possibility of `display`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp), depending of the element you manipulate.